# Sort a string in lexicographic order python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I want to sort a string to a list in lexicographic order as

```
str='aAaBbcCdE'
```

to

```
['A','a','a','B','b','C','c','d','E']
```

but `sorted()` gives me this output:

```
['A','B','C','E','a','a','b','c','d']
```

How can I sort lexicographically?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do not use lambda functions when there's builtin ones for the job. Also never use the `cmp` argument of sorted because it's deprecated:

```
sorted(s, key=str.lower)
```

or

```
sorted(s, key=str.upper)
```

But that may not keep 'A' and 'a' in order, so:

```
sorted(sorted(s), key=str.upper)
```

that will and, by the nature of `sorted` the operation will be very fast for almost sorted lists (the second `sorted`).

Comment: `sorted(sorted(s), key=str.upper)` stands-out.

Comment: Since Python 3.3, str.casefold is a better key function than str.lower or str.upper, as it returns a version of the string suitable for caseless comparisons.

Answer (score 17):

You could use a 2-tuple for the key:

```
text='aAaBbcCdE'
sorted(text, key=lambda x: (str.lower(x), x))
# ['A', 'a', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'd', 'E']
```

The first element in the tuple, `str.lower(x)` is the primary key (making `a` come before `B`), while `x` itself breaks ties (making `A` come before `a`).

Comment: This solved it for me, but I don't understand why returning x doesn't result in correct sorting, but returning (lower(x), x) does.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: @ScottGartner returning a 2-uple `(lower(x), x)` basically uses the already implemented lexicographical ordering of the tuples: all elements that are equal on the index 0 of the tuple will be sorted by the element of the index 1 of the tuple, all elements that are different on index 0 will be sorted as usual.

Comment: This is the best answer by far!

Answer (score 4):

`cmp` was the old way of doing this, now deprecated, but for posterity:

```
s='aAaBbcCdE'
sorted(s, lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()) or cmp(x,y))
```

Comment: that's deprecated use of sorted.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath to be completely obvious, fix your answer and he won't have to.

Comment: @AaronHall: which will make the comments misleading. no, thanks.

Comment: Actually, let's keep this answer here :D

Answer (score 0):

`data = input()
data=list(data)
data.sort()`

Now the variable "data" will have lexicographically sorte`d input provided.

Answer (score 0):

In case you aren't dealing with a collection of simple strings but would still like to sort by natural sort order rather than lexicographic order:

Suppose you have a collection of object instances that you'd like to sort by a particular attribute and the attribute values can start in either upper or lower case then you can do something like this:

```
sorted(objects, lambda object: object.attr1.lower())
```

assuming `attr1` is of type string. Why does this work? Because you are converting all the sorting keys into the same case for the purpose of sorting thus defeating lexicographical sorting. Without the use of lower() or upper() would result in lexicographic sort order rather than natural alphabetical sort order.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) library.
Better to use library than a stackoverflow code solution. (Read somewhere in SO only)