# How to Sort Alphabets

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

**Input**  : `abcdABCD`
**Output** : `AaBbCcDd`

```
ms=[]

n = input()
for i in n:
    ms.append(i)
    ms.sort()
print(ms)
```

It gives me `ABCDabcd`.
How to sort this in python?

Comment: There are __different ways__ of [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) or _alphabetical sorting_, so you could add detailed requirements for your wanted ordering (e.g. always order UPPERCASE letters before lowercase, what about numerical digits, umlauts, etc.). See this [answer which uses python's `sorted` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371935/ddg#7372478) for upper-/lower-case ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Without having to import anything, you could probably do something like this:

```py
arr = "abcdeABCDE"
temp = sorted(arr, key = lambda i: (i.lower(), i))
result = "".join(temp)
print(result) # AaBbCcDdEe
```

The key will take in each element of arr and sort it first by lower-casing it, then if it ties, it will sort it based on its original value. It will group all similar letters together (A with a, B with b) and then put the capital first.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sorting key:

```
ms = "abcdABCD"
sorted_ms = sorted(ms, key=lambda letter:(letter.upper(), letter.islower()))
# sorted_ms = ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd']
sorted_str = ''.join(sorted_ms)
# sorted_str = 'AaBbCcDd'
```

**Why this works:**

You can specify the criteria by which to sort by using the `key` argument in the `sorted` function, or the `list.sort()` method - this expects a function or lambda that takes the element in question, and outputs a new criteria by which to sort it. If that "new criteria" is a tuple, then the first element takes precedence - if it's equal, then the second argument, and so on.

So, the lambda I provided here returns a 2-tuple:

```
(letter.upper(), letter.islower())
```

`letter.upper()` as the first element here means that the strings are going to be sorted lexigraphically, but case-insensitively (as it will sort them *as if* they were all uppercase). Then, I use `letter.islower()` as the second argument, which is `True` if the letter was lowercase and `False` otherwise. When sorting, `False` comes before `True` - which means that if you give a capital letter and a lowercase letter, the capital letter will come first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>>s='abcdABCD'
>>>''.join(sorted(s,key=lambda x:x.lower()))
'aAbBcCdD'
```